# Given a complex PHP object hierarchy can I determine if a string representing a property path exists?

Tags: php, properties

Given a string like "person.addressHistory[2].town" how can i tell if this string points to a property that actually exists. For it to be valid;

1. my object has a person property with a value that is an object.
2. the person object has a property called addressHistory with a value that is an array
3. the addressHistory array must have a key call '2'
4. the value is addressHistory[2] is an object with a property called town

Ideally i want to do something like if (property_exists($myObject, 'person.addressHistory[2].town');

I thought about exploding on the dots then trying to create a recursive function that can drill down into an object heirarchy.

Comment: You might check out https://github.com/lodash-php/lodash-php

Comment: Are the properties of the objects public or private?

Comment: The properties are public

Comment: `json_decode(json_encode($object), true)` will give you an array of the object you can parse the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the exception of the dots `.` this should `eval` correctly.  So let's just replace them:

```
$string = str_replace('.', '->', $string);
$result = eval("return isset(\$myObject->$string);");
```

You can validate for only allowable characters:

```
if(!preg_match('/[^A-Z0-9\[\].]/i', $string)) {
    $string = str_replace('.', '->', $string);
    $result = eval("return isset(\$object->$string);");
} else {
    $result = false;
}
```

Other solutions are possible with the `.` notation but will be long and messy with that array syntax `[n]`.

Comment: I think the dots represent a large part of the point :) - this appears to be an attempt to port of something like what you might do in javascript, for example.

Comment: @cale_b Regardless, they are going to have to be replaced or ignored, recursive function or whatever.

Comment: Nice solution! OP just make sure you sanitize the string before doing this

Comment: This is a neat solution, but is it safe to use eval if the string is coming from a http request parameter?

Comment: @srayner: I wouldn't but you could check, I'll edit a validation.

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer. I don't like the idea of eval, so I went with a more complex solution.